# Can a program break a cpu and/or gpu?

Tags: laptop, memory, paging

For the record I have posted this question on other forums and nobody has a clue. I have an Alienware 14 (Intel i7 4700MQ and GeForce GTX 765M). A while ago I ran an emulated version of the original Legend of Zelda on it, and it somehow managed to fry the CPU and GPU. Here's how I know: I *fully* reinstalled Windows and graphics drivers, but to no avail.

Luckily because of other problems the entire laptop was replaced and it worked just fine (even with the identical old "messed up" system image) until I accidentally opened up the game through Family Share on Steam from another computer. I'm sorry that this sounds like an IT problem, but my general hardware question is: can a program fry a CPU/GPU?

I know if it produced excess heat that could do it, but it didn't get hotter than usual (and thermal throttling would prevent any damage like this). I did notice that it caused a drastic color bit change (when you tab out and look at the desktop its like 8-bit coloration), so maybe it rubbed the GPU the wrong way and fried it? This is the single most bizarre computer problem I've ever seen, and I have done a lot with computers.

EDIT: Here is the emulated Legend of Zelda: http://www.zeldaclassic.com/downloads.php

UPDATE: I am running the game in question right now. According to HW Monitor, temps, power draw, everything is perfectly normal.

SOLUTION: Finally figured out the problem:
1. LoZ caused other programs to hard fault a LOT more than usual and may have kept RAM from cleaning up as much somehow, which
2. Caused much of the RAM to go to the paging file, which
3. Is on my HDD, which apparently is slow as crap (even though I run games off of it just fine), which
4. Caused butt tons of lag.

I had windows remove the paging file and then add it back and it all works swell now. I guess LoZ corrupted the paging file or something, causing this. Moral of the story: don't jump to conclusions. Thanks to those who helped!

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is - maybe you covered fans and CPU/GPU got overheated?

Comment: @Jet I thought of that, but both times this occurred with this specific program. The last time it was on my desk on its feet, so it had airflow.

Comment: Legend of Zelda caused it?

Comment: @Jet Yeah... Not something crazy resource intensive like Folding@Home but the first Zelda game. I blame it on a crappy emulator (or Alienware got an entire bin of GPU's with the same problem)

Comment: Are you sure it’s even using the correct GPU? The device might have GPU switching. Also, how is the CPU fried if you can continue using the device?

Comment: @DanielB That is correct about switching. I'm double-checking to make sure that isn't it, but I'm like 99% sure that isn't it. Binding of Isaac even lags, and that has virtually no GPU usage at all. Also it's not totally broken, just... "handicapped" I guess. Severely diminished performance

Comment: @DanielB Just checked, in both interchanging mode (both discrete and integrated GPU's are available) and discrete mode (only discrete runs) it still has problems.

Comment: I see. Well, the last thing that comes to mind is a firmware bug. Try and get an updated version. Other than that, “power up” the device ~5 times without any power sources and see if that helps.

Comment: @DanielB Will do.

Comment: Both the CPU and GPU are **supposed** to have thermal throttling making it very hard to break these components.  At a certain threshold they usually just shut off completely at the threshold. However,  this can in rare occassion fail.  However, in a laptop if there is too much power draw, amps,the voltage can drop to dangerous level and that can damage the system.  This is a design failure and not software causing the failure.

Comment: Why are you linking to an emulation ROM? One you suspect causes hardware failures...

Comment: The basic answer is YES, for some systems, though it would be very unusual.  One possible scenario would be a system that relied on an interrupt routine to control the fan or throttle the CPU, but a program somehow got caught in a "tight loop" with interrupts disabled.

Comment: (I once had a cellphone get caught in a tight loop and melt the display.)

Comment: Have you ran a system benchmark tool, such as Cinebench?

Comment: @LDC3 Funny enough, yeah just ran Passmark. Everything matches up with standards, but my HDD is slow (although I think that's just how it is anyways). I'm attempting to move a game into a RAMDisk to see if my HDD is causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Can a program break a cpu and/or gpu?

**Short answer:** Yes, a program can break CPU/GPU.

**Long Answer:**
BitCoin miners, bruteforcers (etc) - it's not the first time that GPUs (even best ones with big fans) get damaged because of them. They use GPU very "efficiently" and thus making very high load on GPU (or CPU), so temperature can get higher than when playing the new Battlefield. And if it keeps running for 7-8 hours, then yes it can damage the hardware. For more info, take a look at [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/can-i-damage-my-computer-by-mining-bitcoin) (a question from BitCoin StackExchange site).

And such tools became widespread in pirated software (you download and play a little game and...
they mine money, you lose hardware - BitCoins and malware).

### **What about Legends of Zelda?**

Well, I don't believe that it can be one of those programs (or maybe they put malware inside?).
Maybe you've mistaken, and it's caused by another program?
Maybe it's executable is infected?
Or the worst (less possible) way - their site doesn't seem to be in good state (©1999), maybe it got hacked and executable was changed? Or maybe UFOs? (just kidding ;). I don't know which of these is true.

However, make sure it's caused by LoZ, use temperature monitors ([Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/), [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) etc) to see when it exactly gets hot. Check computer with a good antivirus (don't use free-fake-antiviruses). Install the game on another PC, and check if it gets hot there. 
If it turns out Legends of Zelda, then... (investigation will be continued).

Hope I answered your question!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do a test later with it (even though I think the longer I run it the more it breaks :/  ). I will update this tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: This wasnt  necessarily an "answer" but it was the one that made most sense and actually looked like you had put thought into it :)

Comment: The copyright was 1999 but the website was updated in 2013 (still not good but better). If it was malware it would have still been there when I transferred the hard drives from the old computer to the new computer.

Comment: Yes and that's why it's the least possible way.

Answer (score 2):

Chips (CPU/GPU) are protected with thermal sensors and they should throttle down when they start getting too hot. If these sensors are faulty, or if some software can override this behaviour, then you are going to get thermal damage. This protection is NOT foolproof however. Even when your chips are throttled down, you can still cause overheating if there's no proper cooling. When this occurs, your computer will shut down immediately, but by the time that happens, the heat can stay and still damage the components.

Laptops are not good for gaming because by design, they don't have proper tools to cool down the parts. If you're really into gaming, you should get a proper desktop and preferably one with liquid cooling. It doesn't even have to cost a lot.

But to answer your question whether software itself can cause damage? No. Only the heat that is produced running the software will cause damage. If you cool your system enough, you can run ANY piece of software without damaging your computer.

Comment: Please look at previous answers and add a new one only if it contains new useful information for preventing copied/similar answers in SU.

Comment: My answer is different from other answers. Others say yes, I say 'no'. Provided you have enough cooling capacity, there's no software that can break a processor.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible.

Laptops, especially PC laptops, are notorious for having build-quality problems, particularly related to assembly. These problems include too much / too little thermal paste between components, heatsinks not mounted properly, fans misaligned or stopped, etc. While the laptop may seem to be operating normally under regular desktop applications or even many games, any combination of issues can cause epic failure if the right set of components is pushed to their heat / power limits.

Another common cause of heat-related failure is clogged / blocked air intake / exhaust ports. This is a VERY serious issue which causes heat to build up in the system and can induce failure in any number of components (outside the CPU or GPU).

Long story short - laptops are not ideal for doing heavy CPU+GPU intensive operations. Very few are designed well enough to handle high loads for long periods of time.

Comment: (continue last sentence)... and Alienware is one of them

Comment: It's a gaming laptop though. Because I have had issues with these laptops, I have seen the thing inside and out. It has a very nice heat piping system and the CPU in it beats even midrange custom gaming computer CPU's. The GPU is comparable to a desktop 560 Ti. This game isn't strenuous at all; I run something like Bioshock Infinite or Folding@Home and it actually gets hot. This laptop has sat for weeks on end at 100% CPU and GPU (with a box fan) running Folding@Home, which is more strenuous than even games, and nothing. Run a emulator? Poof. This ONLY happens on this specific program.